# Ignore files that do not contain ".example.js" in their file names .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following situation.I have a folder called configs.
Inside there I have some files which contain the word ".example.js".Now what I want to do for this directory is to ignore the files that do not contain ".example.js",

For example consider `foo.example.js` and `foo.js`.I want to ignore `foo.js`
The reason that I just don't add `foo.js` in my .gitignore is that in that directory there might be more files that do not include `.example.js` like 
`secrets.js` or `settings.js`.Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming `config` folder resides in the root folder of your repository.

Try adding the following two lines to your `.gitignore`:

```
/config/*
!/config/*.example.js
```